# How to copy mysql database from local system to remote server?

Tags: mysql, redhat, openshift

I have a mysql database in my local system I want to copy this database to a server.

I have the following details abt the remote server.

```
Root User: *********
   Root Password: *********
   Database Name: xyz

Connection URL: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
```

Comment: Do you expect OpenShift to copy it for you? does it have that feature? did you try **mysqldump** and restoring the data back on the remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this command on local:

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> <yourdatabasename> > <path_where_want_to_copy_on_local>
```

then go to the location where you dump the database and run:

```
scp <databse_dump_file> your_username@remotehost/some/remote/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps for Openshift (assuming its a nonscalable app):

On your local machine (credit to @uvais):

```
$mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> <yourdatabasename> > <path_where_want_to_copy_on_local>
```

Then port forward:
https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/

And run:

```
$mysql -uadmin -pxxx -h $OPENSHIFT_DB_HOST < <yourbackup>.sql
```

Note: you may have to ssh into your app and cat out $OPENSHIFT_DB_HOST and enter that information in the above command.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to connect your mysql using any mysql interface tool like mysql front or yog than import your .sql to your database from your local machine.

if you have the right to use putty than upload .sql file to your srever and connect to your database using putty and run the below command to import data

```
mysql -u username -p password db < your/.sql.file
```